# Distcc does not find servers

Tags: distcc

I'm sorry that the title is not really telling much, but so far, I can't be more specific...

I have two **Ubuntu 14.04** computers in a network (server (who should do the compiling is at `10.8.1.52`) and the client is at `10.8.1.42`. I installed `distcc` via `sudo apt-get install distcc` and use this config file on the server:

```
>  cat /etc/default/distcc
STARTDISTCC="true"
ALLOWEDNETS="127.0.0.1 10.8.1.0/24"
LISTENER="10.8.1.52"
NICE="10"
JOBS=""
ZEROCONF="false"
```

And `distccd` also is listening:

```
> sudo netstat -taupen | grep distcc
tcp        0      0 10.8.1.52:3632          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      122        24182229    32372/distccd
```

On the client, I set the DISTCC_HOSTS:

```
> echo $DISTCC_HOSTS 
10.8.1.52
```

I know then want to start a compile process on the client (`10.8.1.42`):

```
make -j100 CC=distcc
```

This compiles my code, but only on the client and no work is distributed (although I compile about a dozen .cpp files).

Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: What is the output of `distcc --show-hosts`?

Answer (score 0):

If your error says `distcc found 0 available servers`: Check if your firewall actually is not blocking this port.

From [the distcc wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Distcc#Getting_started):

> Be sure to allow traffic on the port on which distcc runs (the default is 3632/tcp)

Also you mentioned you compile "a dozen .cpp files". Make sure you set the g++ compiler correctly (I assume the compiler is installed on your server):

```
make -j100 CC=distcc CXX=distcc
```

On ther server distcc requires symbolic links to the compilers. Try this [python script](https://github.com/distcc/distcc/blob/master/update-distcc-symlinks.py) if they don't already exist.

For further investigation the documentation on github says:

> If you run into problems it is highly recommended to use DISTCC_VERBOSE=1
> on the client and "--log-level debug" on the server.